# GitHub Action: Cache service responded with 406

Tags: spring-boot, maven, github, github-actions, java-11

I have a GitHub spring boot maven application and my GitHub action  **.github/workflows/main.yml** is as given below. When it executes it is throwing **Error: Cache service responded with 406**

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: 'maven'
        
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

The exception is as shown below

[image]

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this action on a GitHub Enterprise instance? Because caching is (currently) not available on GitHub Enterprise: https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/505

I found this out after getting 406 errors myself.